# Repeat the function with onMouseDown in React

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a program that when we click a button until we release the key, the function runs continuously
In each run, one unit is added up each time and one unit is reduced from the bottom, and each time the result is printed on the console.
I want this operation to be done continuously until the key is released
But I do not know where the problem is that it does not work properly
Please help me, thank you

```
  const [step, setStep] = useState({ top: 0, bottom: 0 });

  let timer;

  function stop() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log(step)
  }

  function handleHello() {
    repeat(() => setStep({ top: step.top + 1, bottom: step.bottom - 1 }));
  }

  function repeat(what) {
    timer = setInterval(what, 100); 
    what(); 
  }

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h3>The output is on the console</h3>
      <button onMouseDown={handleHello} onMouseUp={stop}>
        please press
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: why are you using setInterval function ?

Comment: There is no reason why I thought it might work like this but unfortunately it does not work @HritikSharma

Comment: It worked properly in JavaScript, but it does not work properly in React @HritikSharma

Comment: What do you want this component to do ? I did not understand properly

Comment: Can you create a sandbox ? So that we can collaborate over and help you solve the problem ?

Comment: I want to continuously add `step.top` one unit and decrease one unit of `step.bottom` when we press the mouse button until the mouse key is released. Could I explain clearly? @HritikSharma

Comment: Did you understand my request? @HritikSharma

Comment: Yes, I did understand it now

Comment: What is the use case of this program ?

Comment: Used to change position and want to click and run a continuous function until the mouse click is released
Do you have a solution?
It does not matter what the solution is, just implement it properly @HritikSharma

Comment: I am working on it

Comment: Thank you dear friend for helping me @HritikSharma

Comment: I am able to increment and decrement it rapidly on mouseDown , but not able to stop it on mouseUp

Comment: Guide me as far as you can and see what I can do to stop it @HritikSharma

Comment: Give me some time , I am debugging it . soon will get the answer to it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new?utm_source=dotnew&file=/src/App.js 
This is the link ,

Comment: The code is not in the link, you probably did not save it @HritikSharma

Comment: Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-sun-w46g7g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: can you figure out the problem in the code ?

Comment: I searched and found that we should use `clearInterval()` in react hooks but I do not know how to do this @HritikSharma

Comment: See this link Can you use this to stop our code?    https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-agnesi-7h4v6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark @HritikSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making it mostly correct, but you have a small problem with the timer and `setState`. You should use `useEffect` to track mouse behaviour instead of calling `setState`.

If you're still doubting about it, you can try it out [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-violet-rn9lhd?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

let timer; //you need to have a global variable for your `timer`

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState({ top: 0, bottom: 0 });
  const [isMouseHolding, setIsMouseHolding] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isMouseHolding) { //if holding mouse, we trigger `repeat`
      repeat(() => setStep(prevState => ({ top: prevState.top + 1, bottom: prevState.bottom - 1 })))
    } else {
      stop() //stop it if releasing mouse holding
    }
  }, [isMouseHolding]) //to track mouse holding behaviour changes

    const stop = () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
      setIsMouseHolding(false);
    }
  
    const handleHello = () => {
      setIsMouseHolding(true)
    }
  
    const repeat = (what) => {
      timer = setInterval(what, 100)
    }
  
    return (
      <div style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h3>The output is on the console</h3>
        <button onMouseDown={handleHello} onMouseUp={stop}>
          please press
        </button>
        <div>Top {step.top} and down {step.bottom}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default YourComponent
```

Comment: Can you help me why the `timer` variable should be global?

Comment: When your component gets re-rendered, your timer will be clear too, so when you call `stop`, that timer is not there for the cleanup. @goodboy